# Videojs not working in IE 9 and above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, video.js

I am developing cross browser HTML5 video application. I started experimenting with [videojs](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) for technical possibilities I've developed a page with videojs it is working fine in all browsers but in IE9 & above it is not working. If it works it is loading video with swf not with HTML5 player.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> 
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="video-js/video-js-cust.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="video-js/video.dev.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper{
        width: 760px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .text-center{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .block-video{
        width: 640px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .block{
        background: #e7ecee;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        clear: both;    
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    h4.video-title{
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .modal-content{
        min-width: 680px;
    }
    /** PLAY LIST **/
    .play-list-block{
        height: 480px;
    }
    #video_3{
        float: left;
    }
    .playlist-components{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .playlist{
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
    .playlist ul{
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .playlist ul li{
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .playlist ul li:hover{
        background: #fff;
    }
    .playlist ul li span{
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .playlist ul li span:last{
        float: none;
    }
    .button-holder{
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
    .button-holder #prev{
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .button-holder #next{
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">HTML5 Player technical possibilities</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="block">
            <h4 class="text-center video-title"> Single video play back </h4>
            <video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered block-video"
              controls preload="auto" width="640" height="405"
              poster="videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png"
              data-setup='{"video_1":true}'>
             <source src="videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'></source>
             <source src="videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.webm" type='video/webm'></source>
             <source src="videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg'></source>       
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <h4 class="text-center video-title"> Customizing UI controls </h4>
            <video id="video_2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered block-video"
              controls preload="auto" width="640" height="405"
              poster="videos/Incredibles_Teaser_640x272.png"
              data-setup='{"video_2":true}'>
             <source src="videos/Incredibles_Teaser.mp4" type='video/mp4'></source>
             <source src="videos/Incredibles_Teaser.webm" type='video/webm'></source>
             <source src="videos/Incredibles_Teaser.ogv" type='video/ogg'></source>       
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="block play-list-block">
            <h4 class="text-center video-title"> Play back with multiple videos </h4>
            <!--video id="video_3" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered block-video"
              controls preload="auto" width="640" height="405"
              poster="videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352.png"
              data-setup='{"video_2":true}'>
             <source src="videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.mp4" type='video/mp4'></source>
             <source src="videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.webm" type='video/webm'></source>
             <source src="videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.ogv" type='video/ogg'></source>          
            </video-->
            <video id="video_3" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
                   controls preload="auto" width="570" height="410"
                   data-setup=''
                   poster="">
            </video>
            <div class="playlist-components">
                <div class="playlist">
                    <ul></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="button-holder">
                    <label id="prev" alt="Previous video"> Prev </label>
                    <label id="next" alt="Next video"> Next </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <h4 class="text-center video-title"> Dynamic video loading </h4>

            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
              LOAD PLAYER
            </button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content row">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Player on overlay</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

                    <!-- video id="video_3" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered block-video"
                      controls preload="auto" width="640" height="405"
                      poster="videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352.png"
                      data-setup='{"video_2":true}'>
                     <source src="videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.mp4" type='video/mp4'></source>
                     <source src="videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.webm" type='video/webm'></source>
                     <source src="videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.ogv" type='video/ogg'></source>          
                    </video-->

    <script src="video-js/video-js-playlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video_1_Player = videojs('video_1');
        var video_3_player, video_4_Player, demoModule;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                loadModelPlayer();
            });         
            $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                video_4_Player.pause();
            });         
        });

        function loadPlayList(){
              var videos = [
                            {
                              "src" : [
                                'videos/Incredibles_Teaser.webm',
                                'videos/Incredibles_Teaser.mp4',
                                'videos/Incredibles_Teaser.ogv'
                              ],
                              "poster" : 'videos/Incredibles_Teaser_640x272.png',
                              "title" : 'Video 2'
                            },
                            {
                                  "src" : [
                                    'videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.webm',
                                    'videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.mp4',
                                    'videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.ogv'
                                  ],
                                  "poster" : 'videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352.png',
                                  "title" : 'Video 1'
                            },
                            {
                              "src" : [
                                'videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.webm',
                                'videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.mp4',
                                'videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.ogv'
                              ],
                              "poster" : 'videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png',
                              "title" : 'Video 3'
                            }
                          ];
            //video_3_player = videojs('video_3');
            //video_3_player.playList(videos);
              demoModule = {
                        "init" : function(){
                          this.els = {};
                          this.cacheElements();
                          this.initVideo();
                          this.createListOfVideos();
                          this.bindEvents();
                          this.overwriteConsole();
                        },
                        "overwriteConsole" : function(){
                          console._log = console.log;
                          console.log = this.log;
                        },
                        "log" : function(string){
                          demoModule.els.log.append('<p>' + string + '</p>');
                          console._log(string);
                        },
                        "cacheElements" : function(){
                          this.els.$playlist = $('div.playlist > ul');
                          this.els.$next = $('#next');
                          this.els.$prev = $('#prev');
                          this.els.log = $('div.panels > pre');
                        },
                        "initVideo" : function(){
                          this.player = videojs('video_3');
                          this.player.playList(videos);
                        },
                        "createListOfVideos" : function(){
                          var html = '';
                          for (var i = 0, len = this.player.pl.videos.length; i < len; i++){
                            html += '<li data-videoplaylist="'+ i +'">'+
                                      '<span class="number">' + (i + 1) + '</span>'+
                                      '<span class="poster"><img src="'+ videos[i].poster +'" width="30" height="30"></span>' +
                                      '<span class="title">'+ videos[i].title +'</span>' +
                                    '</li>';
                          }
                          this.els.$playlist.empty().html(html);
                          this.updateActiveVideo();
                        },
                        "updateActiveVideo" : function(){
                          var activeIndex = this.player.pl.current;

                          this.els.$playlist.find('li').removeClass('active');
                          this.els.$playlist.find('li[data-videoplaylist="' + activeIndex +'"]').addClass('active');
                        },
                        "bindEvents" : function(){
                          var self = this;
                          this.els.$playlist.find('li').on('click', $.proxy(this.selectVideo,this));
                          this.els.$next.on('click', $.proxy(this.nextOrPrev,this));
                          this.els.$prev.on('click', $.proxy(this.nextOrPrev,this));
                          this.player.on('next', function(e){
                            console.log('Next video');
                            self.updateActiveVideo.apply(self);
                          });
                          this.player.on('prev', function(e){
                            console.log('Previous video');
                            self.updateActiveVideo.apply(self);
                          });
                          this.player.on('lastVideoEnded', function(e){
                            console.log('Last video has finished');
                          });
                        },
                        "nextOrPrev" : function(e){
                          var clicked = $(e.target);
                          this.player[clicked.attr('id')]();
                        },
                        "selectVideo" : function(e){
                          var clicked = e.target.nodeName === 'LI' ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest('li');

                          if (!clicked.hasClass('active')){
                            console.log('Selecting video');
                            var videoIndex = clicked.data('videoplaylist');
                            this.player.playList(videoIndex);
                            this.updateActiveVideo();
                          }
                        }
                      };
                      demoModule.init();                
        }

        try{
            loadPlayList();
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Exception raised ");
            console.log(err);
        }

        function loadModelPlayer(){
            if(video_4_Player == undefined){
                var videoTag = $("<video>",
                                    {"id":'video_4',
                                     "class":'video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered block-video',
                                     "controls":'true',
                                     "preload": 'auto',
                                     "width":'640px',
                                     "height":'405px'
                                    }
                                );
                var src1 = $("<source>",{"src":'videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.mp4',"type":'video/mp4'});
                var src2 = $("<source>",{"src":'videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.webm',"type":'video/webm'});
                var src3 = $("<source>",{"src":'videos/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.ogg',"type":'video/ogg'});
                $(videoTag).append(src1);
                $(videoTag).append(src2);
                $(videoTag).append(src3);
                $(videoTag).appendTo(".modal-body");
                videojs('video_4',{"width":'640',"height":'405'},function(ev){
                    video_4_Player = this;
                    console.log("player loaded");   
                });
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        /***
        *   CUSTOM SKIN
        ****/
        #video_2 .vjs-big-play-button{
            background: none;
            border: 0px;
            opacity: 1;
            box-shadow: none;
            top: 40%;
        }
        #video_2 .vjs-big-play-button:before{
            text-shadow: none;
            font-size: 2em;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #video_2 .vjs-slider-handle:before {
            font-size: 1.3em;
            text-shadow: none;
            top: -2;
            -webkit-transform: none;
            -moz-transform: none;
            -ms-transform: none;
            -o-transform: none;
            transform: none;            
        }
        #video_2 .vjs-slider-handle:before {
          text-shadow: none;
          -webkit-transform: none;
          -moz-transform: none;
          -ms-transform: none;
          -o-transform: none;
          transform: none;          
        }

        #video_2 .vjs-play-progress{
            background:#b40c1e;
        }
        #video_2 .vjs-volume-handle:before {
            font-size: .9em;
        }   
        .vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-level{
            background: #b40c1e;        
        }       
        #video_2 .vjs-progress-control  {
            font-size: .9em;
        }   
        #video_2:hover .vjs-progress-control {
            font-size: .9em;
            -webkit-transition: none;
            -moz-transition: none;
            -o-transition: none;
            transition: none;
        }
        #video_2 .vjs-control-bar{
            background-color: #07141e;
        }       
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

All resources are loading correctly and it is working in all browsers except IE9 & above.

Please help me where i went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you obtained an HTML5 Shiv?  Sounds like that's what you are missing.